# Dropping duplicated when visualising different granularity in the same df

Tags: data-analysis, analysis

I have a dataset about a bunch of users and their comment on Instagram, each row is a comment. Some of the columns of this table are related to the users and some of them have multiple comments.

I'm doing the EDA and plotting my charts to see some viz about the data but when looking at `follower_count` for example, do I need to subset the data and drop the duplicates before plotting?

I guess it depends and both are valid, but I'd be happy to hear other's opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the duplicates then would that not alter the distribution of your input data?  That in turn would lead to fitting a `posterior` distribution to a different dataset than the original one. Dropping duplicates should likely be done only if they were input data *errors* - for example the data ingestion included one of the files twice.